# Trying to understand CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ascii

I have read many articles explaining what CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) actually are.

I have no problem with CHAR(10), it is simply a line feed or a new line.

I do not understand how CHAR(13) behaves in SQL Server.

See below simple code:

Case 1 - Simple new line
Case 2 - Again, a new line. But why?
Case 3 - 2 new lines. Assuming char(10) and char(13) are returning a new line each (Case 2).
Case 4 - Why 1 new line only?

```sql
PRINT '----------Case 1----------'
DECLARE @str1 nVarchar(MAX) = 'Hello' + CHAR(10) + 'World'
PRINT @str1
PRINT '----------Case 2----------'
DECLARE @str2 nVarchar(MAX) = 'Hello' + CHAR(13) + 'World'
PRINT @str2
PRINT '----------Case 3----------'
DECLARE @str3 nVarchar(MAX) = 'Hello' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'World'
PRINT @str3
PRINT '----------Case 4----------'
DECLARE @str4 nVarchar(MAX) = 'Hello' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'World'
PRINT @str4
PRINT '----------END----------'
```

[See this screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU4fJ.png)

Comment: CR (13) + LF (10) combine to create 1 total carriage return. If you do it in the opposite order, the LF forces the CR to be on a new line, producing 2 carriage returns. It's why in Visual Basic, for example, they call it `vbCrLf`. Always put the carriage return first. If you're just printing stuff in SSMS, though, you only need one or the other.

Comment: If we go to what the root of a CR control key means, move the cursor to the start of the line, it actually shouldn't create a new line. Some (many) tools, however, will infer a CR *without* a following LF to mean to start a new line, even though *technically* it doesn't mean that at all.

Comment: To be honest, this is not a SQL specific thing, it's actually a holdover from some very old machines that needed separate characters. Either CR or LF or CR/LF will make a newline on most modern machines. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Both of these are control characters - that were originally created to send commands to a printer.  The carriage return instructed the printer to move the carriage (print head) back - the line feed advances the paper one line.  For files - the end of line is determined by the default for the platform.  Windows default is CR/LF - Unix default is LF and MAC is CR (or was - may have changed).  Either way, when creating a file in Windows the end of line will be denoted by a combination of CR/LF .